# JQuery Dialog doesn't seem to work with large amount of data

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
JQuery Code in the .ascx page

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDialog(title, message) {
            $("#WarrantCjisResponse").find("#dialogMessage").appendTo(message);
            $("#WarrantCjisResponse").dialog();
        }
    </script>



<!-- button inside of a <ASP:Repeater> -->
<asp:Button id="QDPButton" type="button" Text="QDP"   runat="server"/>

<div id="WarrantCjisResponse" >
     <pre id="dialogMessage"></pre>
</div>

//CODE BEHIND Setting the click handler and the params
button.OnClientClick = "showDialog('QDP','" + Message + "')";
```

If I set "Message" to a small amount of data like "Test", it works.  If I set it to a  large amount of data, it doesn't work, the page just flashes and nothing happens.

Comment: Describe "a large amount of data".

Comment: @JayBlanchard 10 lines of 50 chars per line, with 9 newline chars.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a lot of data. Can you setup a jsFiddle that replicates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the asp:button must have be sending another postback (that I did not capture in the page load).  I replaced the asp:button with a basic `<input>`.  But then, I wasn't able to override the client click from the code behind, so I loaded up the `<input>` with an attribute that held the message, and then in my javascript, I grabbed the message off of it, and used that to fill my Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to append 'message' to `#dialogMessage`, you're using the wrong function. Switch appendTo() with append().

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/